# unique url access control

Tags: urls, user-access

basically I'd like to have my page accessible by only certain listed users which we'll make a unique code.

for example user A will be able to access with an URL like:

> [www.mysite.com/?u=UserA](http://www.mysite.com/?u=UserA)

but when someone accessed with only *[www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)* we'll direct to a **"you don't have access"** page.

of course if user A sent their unique link to other people, others will be able to access, but that's ok for my page.

the reason is that when User A access this page, we'd want to show a "**Welcome to the page User A**" text, and we'll retrieve this creds from the link.

can we use PHP for this? any kind of help is appreciated. thank you in advanced :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check if query string "u" exists, else redirect to your "you don't have access" page.

So something like this:

```
if ( isset($_GET('u')) ) {
    // SHOW YOUR CONTENT
}
else {
    header('Location: https://domain.com/no-access/');
    die();
}
```

Comment: thank you! this works!